# How do I send 0.1 tokens from the Parity client to another address using a custom gas price and CLI only?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, parity

How do I send 0.1 tokens from the Parity client to another address using a custom gas price and CLI only?

Hi,

I want to send 0.1 tokens from my Parity client running on Ubuntu to another address.

I also want to be able to specify the gas price (set a custom gas price) and I only want to use the Parity CLI.

How would I go about doing this?

Vesa

Comment: What do you mean "1 gas fee"? This transaction should cost you 21,000 gas fee.

Comment: No, I think you are referring to "gas limit". When I say gas fee I'm referring to "gas price". Also, I want to know how to set a custom gas price but we don't need to discuss what exact value it should have. I just want to find out how to set the price and make the transaction with Parity CLI.